# Laravel ^6.0 not connect Mysql 5.5.62 with allowOldPassword set to true

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, connection

we have a server with the mysql in the `5.5.62` version, we can't alter the user for not use the old connection password (`allowOldPassword` false), and we can't update the mysql server because the many old services use then.

The question is, how to connect the mysql database with `allowOldPassword` true in Laravel `^6.0`?

Using PDO, for test we can connect using a connection string like this:

```
"DB_USERNAME:DB_PASSWORD@(DB_HOST)/DB_NAME?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local&allowOldPasswords=1&parseTime=true&loc=Local"
```

Comment: Have you tried to set it [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/6.x/config/database.php#L46-L64)?

Comment: Hi, yes, but I not found any options to put into ```options``` array to force the use of ```allowOldPasswords```